Why is my list not updating the value until the next submission/onChange
I am creating a simple list class component in react and for some reason it when the value updates or the button to add to the list is clicked, it adds the previous value instead of the current value. For example if there is " " in the textarea and then I type "e" to make the textarea value be " e", then hit add. It will add " " and not " e". It is only after I hit add again will it display " e" but thats because that is the new previous value. When I try to test in the console after the state has been updated, it still stays the same value and I don't know why since due to the order, it should update before displaying. I might of explained this terribly, bare with me, I suck at explaining issues.


class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listValue: '',
      listAdd: ''
    }

    this.handleList = this.handleList.bind(this);
    this.addValue = this.addValue.bind(this);
  }

  handleList(){
    this.setState({
      listAdd: this.state.listValue
    })
    this.addList(this.state.listAdd);
  }

  addValue(event){
    this.setState({
      listValue: event.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state.listValue);
  }

  addList(value){
    const node = document.createElement("li");
    const textnode = document.createTextNode(value);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.querySelector(".listBox").appendChild(node);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="box1">
        <textarea className="textArea" maxLength={68} onChange={this.addValue}></textarea>
        <button className="submit" onClick={this.handleList}>Add</button>
        <ul className="listBox">

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



